Context in more important than tenses to show duration
Tenses don't always show the duration of verbs  but the verb itself  and context do it. What I mean by that is I could use either simple or continuous tense and write
When I was cooking she arrived to visit me
When I cooked she she  arrived to visit me
Here, even if we use different tenses that may emphasize different things the meaning remains the same. Her visit happened during the process of cooking in both sentences.
Providing that I am right I have a question concering these  examples below
1 When I played a song she arrived
2 When I played a song she jumped and screamed

When I am playing a song she jumps and screamed

Let's start with 1 and 2. As I understand the meaning of these sentences is not obvious and common sense comes na handy. 1 in my opinion means that during my performance she arrived. It doesn't really make sense to assume anything else. Yet, 2 seems to be quite different to me it may imply that during my performance she she jumpes and screames  all the time during my song because she likes it so much or that she jumped for instance once broke her leg and screamed. 3 to me has the same possible meanings as 2. Is that right what I wrote that so much depends on the verb and context and that tenses aren't that important. Do you find my understanding correct?

This is not something native speakers would say: "she arrived to visit me" Make life easier and say (1) "she arrived home" or (2) "she came to visit me"  Your sentence 1 should read When/while  I was playing, she arrived if that is the meaning you want to convey during my performance she arrived Sentence 3 uses the wrong tense. It should be When I am playing a song she jumps and screams.

Whenever I write questions, I spend a long time checking typos, spelling mistakes, presentation (formatting), adding research and improving style. I do my best, because I want my questions to be taken seriously. I never get this impression when I read your posts, I know your questions are sincere but there are always typos, and obvious grammar mistakes which can be easily avoided. They look as if they've been written in 10 minutes (or much less), and posted immediately after. Your questions look like requests for proofreading, and that is strictly off-topic.

When I cooked she she arrived to visit me is completely unidiomatic (quite apart from the repeated word).

I’m voting to close this question because it is too messy.
